# How To Previous Pagination in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I have the 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons. The Next Button is working but when I try to click the Previous button is not working (that method only refresh the document)

Here's my code:

```
private fun getJob(@Nullable lastPage: DocumentSnapshot?, mode: String?) {

    val db = App.context.db
    val qry: Query?

    if (lastPage == null) {
        qry = db.collection("job")
            .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(3)
    } else if (mode == "Next") {
        qry = db.collection("job")
            .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .startAfter(lastPage)
            .limit(3)
    } else {
        qry = db.collection("job")
            .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .endBefore(lastPage)
            .limitToLast(3)
    }

    qry.get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        mPage = snapshot.documents[snapshot.size() - 1]
    }
```

Comment: "is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: when im click the previous button, that method only refresh the document, not give the previous documents..

Comment: Are you sure that the last query returns the right documents? have tried to test without that condition?

Comment: when im hit previous button, on Logcat that query give me the same document when the last im pressed next button not on pass before im click next button,  whats should i tried sir?

Comment: whats the meaning of "without that condition?"

Comment: No, ignore that message. I'll try to simulate myself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `lastPage` in your code is the last **document** on the current page. So that means that if you run this code for the next page:

```
qry = db.collection("job")
    .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .startAfter(lastPage)
    .limit(3)
```

You get the document starting after the last document on the current page, which is exact what you want.

---

But when you run this code to get the previous page:

```
qry = db.collection("job")
    .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .endBefore(lastPage)
    .limitToLast(3)
```

You're getting (up to) 3 documents before the **last document on the current page**. So you end up with two of the same documents as you're currently showing.

---

To paginate in Firestore you need to know the **anchor document**. To paginate forward, that anchor document is the *last* document of the previous page as you currently have, but to paginate backward you need to know the *first* document of the current page instead, so you'll need to track that.

Once you track the *first* document too, the query becomes:

```
qry = db.collection("job")
    .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .endBefore(firstDocumentOnCurrentPage)
    .limitToLast(3)
```